# Edit Online Database (Edit a variable on database table)

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

Issue: I want to edit a variable (a number) on my MySQL database table from the program (new from) I make. what could would allow me to receive the current variable then edit the database online.

Code Using:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports mysql

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim MySQLConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=db4free.net ;port=3306; user id=user; password=password; database=databasetest;"
            MySQLConnection.Open()
            MsgBox("Success!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Failed!")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Programming Language: Visual Studios 13

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 isn't a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are writing this in VB. To interact with a database you will need to send a SQL command. In order to send it a SQL command you will need a `SqlClient.SqlCommand`. After you open your connection to your database your code will be something like the following to update a value on a particular field on a particular table:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = MySQLConnection
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE <your table> SET <your field> = <your number> WHERE <however you would specify the record that needs to be changed>;"
Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
    'Deal with whatever error pops up
End Try
```